# Azure Analysis Service - Not able to connect to Azure Analysis Service instance from SSMS/VS/PowerBI desktop

Tags: azure, saas, azure-analysis-services

I am trying to use Azure Analysis Service in Preview as of today from Microsoft.
I have created a new Azure analysis service instance in Azure portal.
But when I tried connecting to this instance from SSMS/VS/PowerBI - it fails to connect with UnAuthorized error.

Can someone suggest/help if missing anything or of an limitation ?

I am trying to login with AAD account which is added as admin.

Thanks
Sumeet

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have installed the [latest SSMS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx). This [documentation page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/analysis-services-manage/) shows how to connect.

To connect live in Power BI service use the [latest Power BI Desktop](http://powerbi.microsoft.com/desktop?WT.mc_id=Blog_Desktop_Update) and then publish to the Power BI service.

To deploy a model to Azure AS use the [latest SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt).

Answer (score 1):

Clear out any cached credentials by navigating here:

```
C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\AADCacheOM
```

and deleting all files - or at least those that appear relevant.

If that does not work, [download SQL Server Management Studio 17.<latest>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) which appears to have a far better sign in experience for Azure Analysis Services.

[You can find more info here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/analysis-services/analysis-services-manage.md)